# Number recognition in Mathematica

Tags: numerics

Suppose that I have a number $n$ with many decimal digits of precision. What is the code to use to get Mathematica to recognize possible closed-form expressions for that number?

Comment: Try `Rationalize`. Providing more info / examples would be useful,

Comment: http://oldweb.cecm.sfu.ca/projects/ISC/ISCmain.html

Comment: I often use the PSLQ Algorithm, you find it here: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PSLQAlgorithm.html

Comment: Could enter it as a Wolfram|Alpha query. Not sure how well that will fare though.

Comment: As @belisarius notes, you're looking for a Mathematica version of Plouffe's inverter (that's what we used to call the link belisarius provides).

Comment: I don't understand why this one got 4 close votes so far. This functionality _could_ be included in Mma.

Comment: @Dr.belisarius Did you vote to reopen?  Perhaps an upgrade to the question would help?